# Is "wir feiern mit euch mit" correct?

Tags: preposition

We received a wedding invitation with the following sentence to fill in:

```
[x] Wir feiern mit __ Personen mit Euch mit
```

It seems to me that the last "mit" is superfluous but only to the same extent that "mit" is superfluous in `bring deinen Schlafsack mit`, but in German you still generally include it.

Is there a difference between `wir feiern mit Euch` und `wir feiern mit Euch mit`?

Comment: I think the example with the "mitbringen" is differently. You see that there is no double "mit". Other examples which are similar to "mitfeiern" are "mitmachen" or "mitlaufen".

Answer (score 12):

Both sentences `wir feiern mit Euch` und `wir feiern mit Euch mit` are absolutely fine.

In the first sentence you use the verb *[feiern](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/feiern)* in the latter the verb *[mitfeiern](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mitfeiern)*.

Removing *mit Euch* you get the following sentences:

> Wir feiern.
>
> Wir feiern mit.

The former one expresses that we're celebrating, while the second implies that we join a celebration.

That said, it is more obviously that both sentences are also fine when adding "mit Euch", although the second one may sound awkward somehow, because of the double "mit".

---

The "mit" in the other example is necessary.

The sentence

> Bring deinen Schlafsack

is incomplete, although people will understand what you actually meant.

Comment: The doubled "mit" sounds super awkward in my ears. My resolution would be "Wir feiern gerne mit euch und kommen mit __ Personen". Downside: You force the notion that you guest are glad to come ("gerne") into the answer, but I think it reads well.

Comment: 'Wir feiern mit' would also do the trick

Comment: I think the verb is really "mitfeiern", and the other two mits are just additional information. Maybe it's because I'm from the North, to me the double mit doesn't sound awkward. Of course, the solution @0x6d64 provided is a nice alternative.

Answer (score 5):

To make an amendment to Em1's answer: There is a small difference between

> Bring deinen Schlafsack.

and

> Bring deinen Schlafsack mit.

In the second sentence someone is asked to bring *along* the sleeping bag, the first sentence sounds like you want the other person to bring the sleeping bag over, and then leave. However, if we talk about an invitation everybody understands that they are welcomed to stay and not just "bring the sleeping bag": In every other case the other person would state explicitly some kind if request:

> Ich hätte da eine Bitte [an dich]: Könntest du...

Comment: Hahaha, ja. Daran hab ich gar nicht gedacht. In dem Kontext ist der Satz natürlich richtig; wobei noch immer ungeklärt wäre, wohin ich den Schlafsack bringen soll ;)

Comment: *Bring deinen Schlafsack*, even in the mentioned context, still sounds incomplete (actually: denglisch) to me. You would include some word, like *Bring deinen Schlafsack vorbei* or *Bring mir deinen Schlafsack*.

Answer (score -2):

> Wir feiern mit 84 Personen mit Euch mit

Das doppelte mitfeiern kann nur einen Grund haben: Es soll unterstrichen werden, dass die Gastgeber selbst feiern, und dass man deren Feiern in der Intensität nicht erreichen wird, und nur teilnimmt am Feiern.

Würde jmd. zum Viertelfinale der EM einladen, und großspurig ankündigen den Sieg über Italien mit uns feiern zu wollen, so wäre dies, auch wenn es eine Rollenverteilung Gastgeber/Gast gibt, ansonsten ein Feiern unter gleichen. Hier würde ein

> Wir feiern ... mit Euch mit

unpassend sein. Dagegen, wenn Löw den Titel erringen würde, und er würde zum Abschluß eine Siegesfeier veranstalten, könnten Spielerfamilien eingeladen werden mitzufeiern. "Wir haben den Titel aktiv gewonnen, aber Ihr sollt mitfeiern."

Comment: I think this qualifies as "social skills of a thermonuclear device", especially the first paragraph, unless you're trying to be sarcastic, but then it's simply not funny. Did you ever meet someone who would write an invitation like that and actually mean what you suggested? I agree that there may be better alternatives, like the one 0x6d64 suggested, but that doesn't make the original sentence having such a mean meaning. Never attribute to malice what may just be colloquial usage.

Comment: @OregonGhost: Ich versteh Dich nicht. Was konkret erscheint Dir am ersten Absatz falsch zu sein? Meinst Du dass die, die solch eine Einladung aussprechen die soziale Feinfühligkeit eines Atomsprengkopfes haben, oder ich, der ich den Text derart interpretiere? M.a.W.: Ja, ich habe solche Personen getroffen die sich stundenlang über die Formulierung eines Satzes unterhalten können, und verschiedene Lesarten gegeneinander abwägen, und zu erraten versuchen, was wer falsch verstehen könnte. Das führt in der Regel zu Sätzen die nicht locker rüberkommen, das schaffen dann nur Genies der Diplomatie.

Comment: Ich schildere die Person nicht abfällig - da liest Du zuviel aus Deiner Phantasie rein. Es geht aber um ein Hochzeitspaar, das üblicherweise sehr verliebt ist, und sich narzisstischen Größenphantasien hingibt, wie das bei der Liebe so ist. Das ist ein normaler Vorgang, aber ich muss die Illusion nicht teilen. Sollen sie ihre Sonderstellung auf der Feier ruhig betonen. Wie kommst Du auf die Idee, dass ich Differenzierung kritisiere?